# How to avoid the tiny white line between clipped areas and gobbed line width

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

The is a tiny unwanted white line between blue areas (it is a MWE ;-) ) and the black border line is cut by the clipping line. How to avoid this two problems ?

It's not visible on a png image but very annoying on a pdf.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\clip[rotate=45] (-1,-1) rectangle (0,1) ;
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip[rotate=45] (1,-1) rectangle (0,1) ;
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any rotation, this is what your code gives:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\clip[rotate=0] (-1,-1) rectangle (0,1) ;
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The cuts are clearly seen. With some shifts as below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\clip[rotate=0] ([shift={(-0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]-1,-1) rectangle ([shift={(0.5\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)}]0,1) ;
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can give appropriate `shift` with a magnitude of `\pgflinewidth` to your actual code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\clip[rotate=45] ([shift={(-\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)}]-1,-1) rectangle ([shift={(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)}]0,1) ;
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip[rotate=45] ([shift={(\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth)}]1,-1) rectangle ([shift={(0.5\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)}]0,1) ;
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact `0.5\pgflinewidth` would be enough, but to be on safer side `\pgflinewidth` has been used.

Comment: You shot too fast ;-)

Comment: @Tarass Only some times ;)

Comment: By default the line is drawn on the path. I hoped there was an option like inner to draw the line inside the path, outer to draw the line around the path (cycle) ?

Comment: @Tarass No, it is only the `pgflinewidth`